# Access USART1 on NUCLEO-F030R8

Tags: stm32, uart

Is it possible to access USART1 on the NUCLEO-F030R8 board? the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf) does not mention it at all (only bringing up USART2), but according to the specifications of the processor it should be possible as the PA10 and PA9 (rx and tx) pins are on the developement board.

I'm not getting any errors when trying to print from it, but i'm not getting any output. The same code works great when using USART2.

Comment: What gpio pin did you set the alternate function to for this uart output and what do you have hooked up to that uart output?  What does the scope show?

Comment: Not all of the NUCLEO boards support the virtual uart function through the debug/stlink MCU.  And they are not extremely detailed about it.  The first clue is if the debug MCU TX/RX pins are by default connected to the target mcu, or if the solder bridge is open by default.  If closed by default then just setup your uart right, if open by default the board probably does not support this mode and you have to use some other uart to talk to the part (an ftdi breakout board for example).

Comment: @old_timer i used a usb-ftdi chip (ftdi232) to communicate with the stm32, and the scope doesn't show any communications. 
I can't find anything about any jumpers connecting to PA9 or PA10, but there is one for PA2 and PA3 (the usart that is working)

Comment: looking at that board, and apparently I have one laying around somewhere as I wrote some examples for it at one point in time.  Both usart1 and 2 are listed as alternate function for PA 2 and 3.  so even though the board documentation says ustart2 is available on 2 and 3, both usart1 and 2 should be available there

Comment: Likewise several other pins can be used for usart1.  For the pa2/3 or pa9/10 case it should just be a matter of using a different alternate function selection and use the uart1 base address rather than uart2 when programming.